# Read/Write in Memory Mapped files in C++ using Boost

Tags: c++, boost

I'm a newbie to the world of Boost and was trying to Read/Write in memory mapped binary files. But I don't really know what to do actually and stuck somewhere in between. To be precise, I want my binary file to be memory mapped and then perform read/write operations on it.
Till now, I've been trying to do stuff like :

```
stream_buffer<file_sink> is("test.txt");
std::ostream out(&is);
out << "This is written to file." << std::endl;
is.close();
```

Please help me understand how to proceed for this kind of problem. 
A POC would be great to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [example](https://github.com/apolukhin/Boost-Cookbook-4880OS/blob/8f977e9e0d67eaf66c4dc3f21651d96ed33a0af7/Chapter11/reading_files/main.cpp) from the [book "Boost C++ Application Development Cookbook"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849514887) available on [GitHub](https://github.com/apolukhin/Boost-Cookbook-4880OS)

Comment: I've already gone through the doc part, still not able to get few things.
See what i want is to map my file to memory, perform read / write operations on it and the changes should be visible on my file stored on disk.

    file_mapping fm(argv[1], mode);
    mapped_region region(fm, mode, 0, 0);
    void* add = region.get_address();
    char* begin = static_cast<char*>(add);
    cout << "Mapped region size : " << region.get_size();
  string mystr("Voila ! Good Morning. In new line. Hello.  ");
  cout << endl << mystr.size() << endl;
  memcpy(begin, mystr.c_str(), mystr.size() + 1);

Comment: But the problem is that mapped_region is a fixed memory. But my string can be of any length. So i want something that doesn't need to depend on size or i can alter the size according to length of my string.

Comment: @naiveCoder usually you unable to change size except by re-mapping http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096485/how-to-dynamically-expand-a-memory-mapped-file Keep in mind that it's not exactly the file - it virtual memory blocks, so do not expect file behaviour.