# Adding new bytes to memory mapped file

Tags: c, pointers, winapi

How i can add new info to memory mapped file ?
Using a pointer I can work with existing data, but only within their current size. Is it so ? For example:

```
void  DemoFileMapping()
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("1.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

    DWORD d;
    char * str = "ABCDEFG";
    WriteFile(hFile, str, strlen(str), &d, 0);

    HANDLE mapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, 0);
    if (mapping)
    {
        unsigned char * buf = (unsigned char *)MapViewOfFile(mapping, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
        if (buf)
        {
            buf[2] = 'Z'; // it works!
            UnmapViewOfFile(buf); 
        }
        CloseHandle(mapping);
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

But how can I add new information to the current one? For example, extend the string to "ABCDEFGHIJK"? 
I would like to have solutions without a banal backup of a larger area than the file size.

Comment: Use WriteFile again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically expand a Memory Mapped File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096485/how-to-dynamically-expand-a-memory-mapped-file)

Comment: @zett42 - fanny that there was wrong answer. we **can** extend section (or file maping - this is aliases) if we create it with `SECTION_EXTEND_SIZE` access. exist special api - `ZwExtendSection` - so really task is possible and simply. but need use not documented ntdll api

Comment: [You dont need to cast the result of functions returning `void*` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if I correct understand your question - you ask - are possible extend section (memory mapped file) after it was created. Yes. but for this need use *ntdll* api.

`CreateFileMapping` this is **restricted** shell over [`ZwCreateSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566428(v=vs.85).aspx). if you look for it second parameter - *DesiredAccess [in]* - you can note next access flag:

> *SECTION_EXTEND_SIZE*  - Dynamically extend the size of the section.

Speaks for itself. but however *MSDN* not explain how extend the size of the section. for this exist next api - [`ZwExtendSection`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntzwapi_8h.html#ab6db1bdb1a5b280f04775009ccb4ce96) but on current time it not documented at all (*but it present and worked how minimum from win2000 up to latest win 10*). what sense document flag `SECTION_EXTEND_SIZE` without document `ZwExtendSection` I don't understand. also in documentation from [`ZwCreateSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566428(v=vs.85).aspx) - *MaximumSize [in, optional]* - the name of parameter is not correct. this is faster Initial section size, but not Maximum - because we can extend section.

also about [`ZwExtendSection`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntzwapi_8h.html#ab6db1bdb1a5b280f04775009ccb4ce96) - it extend section to *NewSectionSize* (*if it more then current section size - otherwise call will be have no effect*) rounds this value up to the nearest multiple of *PAGE_SIZE* and if section based on file - it extend file too, and *NewSectionSize* will be new file size - exactly byte to byte. file size will be **not** rounded to *PAGE_SIZE*

but if section already mapped at some *BaseAddress* - are view of section will be also automatically extended ? this depended from how map view of section. if by call `MapViewOfFile(mapping, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);` *no*. so you will be need unmap and then map section again after extend.

but is you will be use [`ZwMapViewOfSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566481(v=vs.85).aspx) with *AllocationType [in] == MEM_RESERVE* in this and only in this case *ViewSize* can be bigger than current section size (without `MEM_RESERVE` flag you got error if *ViewSize* bigger than current section size) - in this case system reserves *ViewSize* of the process's virtual address space but commit only current section size (*may be little more pages*). and when you call `NtExtendSection` - the committed view size will be extended up to *NewSectionSize*. this is similar when we first call [`VirtualAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) with big *ViewSize* and `MEM_RESERVE` for reserve process's virtual address space without allocating any actual physical storage in memory and than again call [`VirtualAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) with *NewSectionSize* and `MEM_COMMIT` flag. even not similar but exactly, only indirect.

before win8.1 no alternative for call [`ZwMapViewOfSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566481(v=vs.85).aspx) if we want use `MEM_RESERVE` flag, but from 8.1 we can use for this [`MapViewOfFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx) too with flag `FILE_MAP_RESERVE`. it declared in `memoryapi.h` from *SDK* as

```
#define FILE_MAP_RESERVE    0x80000000
```

but by unknown reason not documented in MSDN. I check this flag - it worked (how I say from win 8.1 only)

demo/test program can be next:

```
void DemoFileMapping()
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"1.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        HANDLE hSection;

        // set for demo intial size of section to 2 byte
        // NtCreateSection rounds this value up to the nearest multiple of PAGE_SIZE. 
        // however this will be have effect for file size exactly, if current file size less than this value
        LARGE_INTEGER InitialSize = { 2 };
        NTSTATUS status = NtCreateSection(&hSection, 
            SECTION_MAP_WRITE|SECTION_MAP_READ|SECTION_EXTEND_SIZE, 0, &InitialSize, 
            PAGE_READWRITE, SEC_COMMIT, hFile);

        //we can close file handle now
        CloseHandle(hFile);

        if (0 <= status)
        {
            PVOID BaseAddress = 0;
            SIZE_T ViewSize = 0x1000000;//reserve 16 Mb memory for example

            // BaseAddress = MapViewOfFile(hSection, FILE_MAP_RESERVE|FILE_MAP_READ|FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, ViewSize);
            // note MEM_RESERVE
            if (0 <= ZwMapViewOfSection(hSection, NtCurrentProcess(), &BaseAddress, 0, 0, 0, 
                &ViewSize, ViewUnmap, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE))
            {
                LARGE_INTEGER NewSize = { 0x20001 };// some random new size (128k+1 byte)

                // this call extend file, section and view size
                if (0 <= ZwExtendSection(hSection, &NewSize))
                {
                    memset(BaseAddress, '*', NewSize.LowPart);
                }

                UnmapViewOfFile(BaseAddress);
            }

            CloseHandle(hSection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the file is still limited in size of ViewSize ? If I expand the area more than the size of ViewSize,  then I can not write to it. For example: NewSize = { 0x20001 }, ViewSize = 0x20000. ==> The file received a size 0x20001 But the last byte did not include an '*'. If you need to extend the file to a size larger than ViewSize then we need to recreate the View with new ViewSize?

Comment: @Evgen8 - you not understand - `ViewSize` at all not related to file size. this is only size of reserved memory. I write about this. if you set `NewSize > ViewSizw` in call `ZwExtendSection` - the file and section will be extended, but view of section no. how I write - in this case you need remap - unmap current view and map it again. so the best - select very big range of memory for initial `ViewSize`. this not make file big - no effect on file. this not cause to big memory allocation, only reservation or region

Comment: compare ways. by write file or `SetEndOfFile` you will be need - 1)call `SetEndOfFile` for extend file. 2) `UnmapViewOfFile` 3)`CloseHandle` for section. 4) `CreateFileMapping` again 5.) `MapViewOfFile` - again. and you can got new base for view of section. in same case- if you hold pointers to data in this view - you need rebuild this pointers. in undocumented way - if you reserve big enough memory space - you need single call `ZwExtendSection` - not 5 calls to kernel. and base address of view not changed. if you not reserve memory for section at begin - need be 3 calls - + Unmap and Map View

Comment: Ok. So, can I use this in a 64 bit program? In the 32-bit program works, and for 64 I get an error from the function ZwMapViewOfSection:

Comment: An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function as the third argument. Because of the 64-bit pointer ... It is necessary to use mapping in the 64-bit application.

Comment: @Evgen8 - `I use this in a 64 bit program?` of course . this code at all absolute independed from 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: @Evgen8 - `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_3` this when you not initialize `BaseAddress` to 0 or too large (negative) `ViewSize`

Comment: Forgive me for importunity) What strategy is used to reduce the file size? ZwExtendSection() - Is there no function to reduce the region? NtCreateSection() - From the solutions just re-create a region with a smaller InitialSize and re-map file? Is there no other way?

Comment: @Evgen8 - `ZwExtendSection` only increment section (and file, if section on file) size, but never decrement. for decrement file size you need call `SetFileInformationByHandle` with `FileEndOfFileInfo` but if you this while section mapped - you got error - `ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE` so only way - unmap and close section. set new file size and again create section on it